# Problema con sentencia mysql en php

Tags: php

No me da ningún error pero no me sube a la base de datos.

Si le pongo comillas de una '' me sale error de sintaxis en $nombre pero si le pongo "" no me da error pero tampoco sube nada a la base de datos.

```
       mysqli_query($conect, "INSERT INTO Clientes 
    (nombre,apellido,direccion,provincia,ciudad,zip,fono,email) VALUES 
    ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$direccion', '$provincia', '$ciudad', 
     '$zip', '$fono', '$email')");
```

Comment: Buenas Vinicio, ¿Has confirmado si realiza bien la conexión?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir algo más de código? Por ejemplo ¿Cómo realizas la conexión? ¿Estás comprobando que la conexión es válida?

Comment: Hola @Vinicio, deberías agregar más código en el contexto de esa línea para ver si estás haciendo los controles de error oportunos. Tal y como lo tienes asumo que no, por lo que mi respuesta te ayudará a descubrir el error que estás cometiendo.

Comment: si tod esta bien es mas en otra parte realizo la subida a la base de datos en otra tabla y no da problemas peor no se que le pasa me sale este error ERROR SQL: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @VinicioMoyaAlmeida , ¿podrías comunicarte conmigo [a través del chat que abrimos (enlace)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67524/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-problema-con-sentencia-mysql-en-php) para el tema? Gracias. Si este problema en particular se ha solucionado agradecería que pulsaras la marca **✔** que hay a la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

El primer problema que sufres (*si le pongo comillas de una '' me sale error de sintaxis en `$nombre` pero si le pongo "" no me da error pero tampoco sube nada a la base de datos*) es debido a que las [comillas simples](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.single) no interpretan el contenido de las variables dentro de una cadena de caracteres, con [comillas dobles](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double) sí.

Además, si pones comillas simples debes escapar las comillas simples que delimitan las variables o se entenderán que son parte de PHP y no del SQL:

```
$a = '('$pepito')';
```

Tras la cadena '(' hay una variable sin un operador intermedio, lo mismo ocurre con la cadena final ')'. La forma correcta de escapar comillas simples sería:

```
$a = '(\'$pepito\')';
```

Tu código no tiene control de errores, por lo que si la consulta está produciendo un error de sintaxis, clave duplicada, etc, no te enterarás del problema.

Además, es una mala práctica introducir variables de manera directa en una consulta SQL. Podrías sufrir problemas de sintaxis SQL si alguna contiene caracteres especiales como comillas simples u otros, abriendo la puerta a ataques de inyección SQL que son [un problema muy grave a tener en consideración](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY).

### Solución propuesta

Si no quieres usar consultas preparadas con [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) entonces te recomiendo escapar el contenido de las variables con [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string).

```
/* Escapamos caracteres especiales de todas las cadenas agregadas al SQL */
$resultado = mysqli_query(
  $conect,
  "
    INSERT INTO Clientes 
    (
      nombre,
      apellido,
      direccion,
      provincia,
      ciudad,
      zip,
      fono,
      email
    ) VALUES (
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $nombre) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $apellido) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $direccion) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $provincia) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $ciudad) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $zip) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $fono) . "',
      '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conect, $email) . "'
    )
  "
);
/* En caso de haberse producido algún error durante la ejecución de
     la consulta anterior mostramos el mensaje de error */
if ($resultado === false) {
  die('ERROR SQL: ' . mysqli_error($conect));
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67524/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-problema-con-sentencia-mysql-en-php).